# Converting to ogg via avconv - Unknown encoder 'libtheora' (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, ffmpeg, avconv

In Ubuntu 16.04 I am trying to convert a video using

```
"input.avi" -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 "out.ogv"
```

but I get this error:

```
Unknown encoder 'libtheora'
```

The were no errors in Ubuntu 14.04. What can I do?

Comment: I think ffmpeg liks to avconv on my PC

Comment: 16.04's FFmpeg can use libtheora by default. Try running `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` and see if this produces a result... And can you please give the full command line and complete terminal output? Perhaps to paste bin might be best.

Comment: As andrew.46 mentioned showing the full command and the complete console output will help solve this properly instead of having to use a package from a PPA that is designed for an older Ubuntu release.

Comment: @Crantisz  I have created an answer that hopefully explains the `libav-tools` situation under Xenial as well as showing how to safely resolve your quandary :). Note: best to lose the older PPA as LordNeckbeard has advised...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this:
Add ffmpeg PPA:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media

Next in synaptic I find `ffmpeg` and in menu: `Package –> Force Version` set older one.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus LTS does indeed still have a package named `libav-tools`:

```
andrew@athens:~$ apt-cache policy libav-tools
libav-tools:
  Installed: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and thus still has `avconv`. However all of the executables in the `libav-tools` package are *pointers to related FFmpeg executables*:

```
andrew@athens:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/{avconv,avplay,avprobe}
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Mar 15 06:32 /usr/bin/avconv -> ffmpeg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Mar 15 06:32 /usr/bin/avplay -> ffplay
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 15 06:32 /usr/bin/avprobe -> ffprobe
andrew@athens:~$
```

Now FFmpeg can be tested for libtheora encoding as follows, a test I have undertaken on my Xenial installation:

```
andrew@athens:~$ ffmpeg -encoders 2>/dev/null | grep theora
 V..... libtheora            libtheora Theora (codec theora)
```

So a stock, unmodified installation of FFmpeg (or the dummy `libav-tools` package) *can successfully encode video using libtheora*.

My best advice to you is to completely remove all copies of FFmpeg or libav-tools on your system, as well as *totally remove FFmpeg PPAs for older versions of Ubuntu*, and then simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra
```

And all will be well :)

Comment: Far as I know, ffmpeg built with codecs and dont use system codecs. Anyway, these packages have been installed in my system

Comment: @Crantisz FFmpeg uses its own codecs but any thing marked with 'lib' designates an external library, libtheora is one of these. Your copy of FFmpeg from mc3man's PPA is an older version that is designed for Trusty, there is a better version available natively from the Xenial Repositories.